# Converting HTML Files to PNG Images

Tags: python, html-to-pdf

I'm parsing a site and retrieving a div. For the past few days I have been trying to find a library that can turn this div into a .png image. Is there any way I can do this without using a REST API? Any python libraries that can export to png? I have tried HTML2PNG(white background), imgkit(can't render gradients). I'd appreciate any advice, suggestions and information. Thank you :) I can also export to PDF and convert it to PNG from there, if I can get the transparency.

Things I need to do:

- Load External CSS.
- Export **only the div** to PDF/PNG with transparent background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`weasyprint`](https://pypi.org/project/WeasyPrint/)

```
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS

div = 'your div as string'
css_string = 'your css as string'

html = HTML(string=div)
css = CSS(string=css_string)
html.write_png('output.png', stylesheets=[css])
```

**EDIT:**
As of current stable version `59.0b1` `weasyprint` no longer supports the function `write_png` ([See here](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/api_reference.html#weasyprint.HTML))

Comment: Looks like there's a `write_png` for writing directly to PNG, too.  Didn't see any mention of transparency though.

Comment: Yes @MarkRansom sorry for the typo, it should be `write_png`, I updated the answer. The png background is transparent by definition, unless you stipulate otherwise in the css.